# How can I get uppercase of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I need to get the uppercase (or lowercase) of a string in Javascript, but that string can contain special characters of any alphabet in UTF-8 (for example, spanish `ñ` or `ç`, german `ä`, `ö` or `ü`, etc.).

How can I get this?

Comment: May be the plain `.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: "ñ".toUpperCase()

Comment: There’s `.toLocaleUpperCase()`, but it uses the current locale; you can’t set it.

Comment: I didn't thought it was so easy ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `toUpperCase()`:

```js
console.log('ñç'.toUpperCase());
```